# Angularjs: alternative to injecting $http into module.config

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

So, I'm trying to use ui-router states in my app. The app displays information about items, and depending on the type of the item, the layout of the page will vary wildly. Therefore, I have a bunch of completely separate html pages, one for each item type.

A user might hit a url like the following: 'app/items/id:18273981729'. In that case, I want to strip off the id, send out an http GET request to hit a database, retrieve the item with that id, check what type of item that is, and route the user to the correct html page, depending on the type of the item whose id he/she specified.

I have generally tried to do the following:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $http) {
    $stateProvider.state('display', {
        url: 'app/items/:itemId',
        templateUrl: function(attrs) {

            var url = '';

            // use $http.get to get the item from the database,
            // check it's type, and return the correct URL
            $http.get('/api/items/' + attrs.itemId).success(
                function(data) {
                    var itemType = data['itemType'];
                    switch (itemType) {
                        case 'type1':
                            url = 'url1';
                        case 'type2':
                            url = 'url2';
                    }
                }
            );

            return url;
        },
        controller: 'displayCtrl as display'
    });
});
```

As I now know, since $http is a service, it cannot be injected into module.config. I've heard that services can be injected into the run function, but nothing works when I replace "config" with "run" in the pseudocode above. What other options do I have here? I'm not sure how to accomplish my goal.

Comment: It wont work even if you were to get `$http` via the $injector, because you are doing it async. COnsider using httpInterceptor where you can return a promise in the request function.

Comment: You can use the resolve object to do logic, you can only call Providers from config, i.e. $httpProvider.  You can create a provider that has $http injected into it and call that provider from your resolve object

Comment: @JacobCarter, since you can inject providers into module.config, and since you aren't allowed to inject services into module.config, why would you be allowed to inject a service into a provider? Wouldn't that allow people to break the rules and sneak a service into config?

Comment: I don't know where you guys got the notion that you can't use $http directly in a resolve function, but that's wrong. You can: http://plnkr.co/edit/KsBo1OlIgOfF4Tn8am7n?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named function with `$inject` module. try this

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $http) {
    $stateProvider.state('display', {
        url: 'app/items/:itemId',
        templateUrl: templateFn,
        controller: 'displayCtrl as display'
    });
});

templateFn.$inject = ['$http'];


function templateFn(attrs) {

            var url = '';

            // use $http.get to get the item from the database,
            // check it's type, and return the correct URL
            $http.get('/api/items/' + attrs.itemId).success(
                function(data) {
                    var itemType = data['itemType'];
                    switch (itemType) {
                        case 'type1':
                            url = 'url1';
                        case 'type2':
                            url = 'url2';
                    }
                }
            );

            return url;
        }
}
```

Comment: the $inject property is undefined here

Comment: @ZacharyForster nope. $inject is not undefined. its a pre-define angular module. check it out docs [$inject] (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: but when I use that code, it fails because templateFn has no property $inject.. did you mean "templateFn.$inject = ['$http']" instead of "templateFn.$inject['$http']"?

Comment: @ZacharyForster oh yes, sorry. U right. I updated it. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the templateProvider which is injectable. In there you can fetch data, do your logic and return the template based on that:

```
'templateProvider': [
    '$http',
    function ($http) {
        return $http.get('a.json').then(
            function (response) {
                return $http.get(response.data.type + '.html').then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
]
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gBi1LAJ8rmv6a3d1t9Gl?p=preview